# Launch asyc a method from a class in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I am using C++14 and would like to launch a method from a class instance which is stored in unique_ptr. A very simple version of my code looks like:

```
class foo {
  void run_server() {
    // Do some stuff.
  }
};

auto ptr = make_unique<foo>();
auto res = std::async(std::launch::async, ptr->run_server());
```

I get compile error when I compile my code and the error message says that there is no match to call async. I think there is a way to launch methods of an instantiated class using lambda function but I am not sure how or whether this is a solution in my case. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What does the example for doing this, in your C++ textbook, look like?

Comment: if you ignore the async, what does the expression `ptr->run_server()` denote?

Comment: My intention is to run the server as a non-blocking process on a separate thread. Of course I can directly call ptr->run_server() but in that case the server code will block the execution.

Comment: Who shall run the server? Is it your code, by calling `ptr->run_server()` or is it `std::async` that runs the server? Look at your code closely. You can also debug the code and watch what happens in which order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda to achieve this BUT passing a unique_ptr to a lambda means you move it to lambda and then it is destroyed when the lambda returns.

You could try this:

```
class foo {
public:
    void run_server() {
        // Do some stuff.
    }
};

int somefunc() {
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<foo>();
    auto p = ptr.get();

    auto theasync=std::async( [p]{ std::launch::async, p->run_server() ;});
    //do whatever...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve the problem by calling the method of the class in the following way:

```
auto res = async(launch::async, &foo::run_server, ptr.get());
```

The solution with lambda may also work.